Error while compiling Prusa-Firmware-Buddy
I'm trying to compile Prusa-Firmware-Buddy according to the instructions at the readme file: https://github.com/prusa3d/Prusa-Firmware-Buddy
Looks like all python requirements are being installed automatically when I open VSCode and when I run utils/build.py.
But I'm getting this error:
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Prusa-Firmware-Buddy/.dependencies/cmake-3.28.3/bin/cmake'
The cmake version I have is 3.28.3 and I tried also with 3.29.6.
Appreciate your help. Thanks.
